# Why compilation doesnt fail in an empty class with use of generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics, compilation

The compilation doesnt fail when i use an empty class and call it into a generic typed class :

[View Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgFwBYEsB2BzAPACoB80A3gLABQ0t0w82EqATgK7CrwsAUADi0wA3MKmTQQmZgC5ohAJTkAvtRVVqAeg3QAtHv0HDR6AGEAgrACi0AIzRZhABIBJWNFfQAcgHkASgFkzABlqUEgYWHRkZD4ANTtKGjoBYVFxBhBuWWZBPGgAXmgAIhZkABMigG5ValDwKGgAIWQWXBb48mo6aBSRMXp4TJZs1hxcAuLSiuqqNS1oSwAPPmROcvtoADMwTBB1hkQ+XeRNbUIogcPd0UxGLZ2QGFlMVAByGGxuRDAQaB5gSDibAABps8mo2GQAHc4Eg0Fg8Phmq12jZiDxITDItE4jYePJ5DNalR5kYyeTTBZrAAmDZODweWCEXxmTwAcUsxLCDWxMVitMS3V6aQGQxGuXGhRK5SqNXUVG5MGRbRY-M6s2J8yWKzWZQ222OeoORz2pzkF2N11Qt2w912T2gL3e0E+LG+v3+gJdwOp4KomNhKAwY3wvLi1PRAeV7Wp+MJmu02tWYj1sgNeyNSBNJxJZwtWatNugZXgyAg2FQdseGyh6AAntAAPzN5sQ6GB+Eh6OqiMY9th-lxolUIA)

Comment: Why should it fail? What error do you think it should have failed with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Argument of type 'SheepV1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BergerV1'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'color'.`
```

You're declaring the same private property in your first example, and not in your second. In your second example you're allowed to cast it because your class shapes are compatible.

For example, if you add a `private otherColor: string = "blue";` to your empty class it'll say that they're incompatible:

```
Argument of type 'SheepV2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BergerV2'.
  Property 'newColor' is missing in type 'SheepV2' but required in type 'BergerV2'.
```

These 2 are essentially the same problem, except in the first it's because it declares the same properties. And it the second because they aren't compatible.

---

Edit: To expand and get a clearer error, if you try this with the empty class setup:

```
const test1: BergerV1 = new SheepV1() as BergerV1;
const test2: BergerV2 = new SheepV2() as BergerV2;
```

You'll get this error for V1 and none for V2:

```
Conversion of type 'SheepV1' to type 'BergerV1' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'color'.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I think i understand. 

Ive updated the playground with "case n°2" to illustrate.